# Angles with oblique incidence and polarization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, optics, geometric-optics, polarization

I need help with a exercise, i have problem with angles.

A circular wave of left hand with |E| = 1 V / m affects the interface between two media with refractive indices n1 = 1.45 and n2 = 4.1 with an incidence angle of 40 °. Determine the polarization characteristics of the reflected wave and the transmitted wave in detail, indicating amplitudes, rotation angles and ellipsicity.

So we can calculate the transmitted angle with Snell law (t=10.14°) and get the reflexion(R) and transmission(T) coeficients, TE and TM.

Rte = -0.5647

Tte = 1+Rte = 0.4353

Rtm = 0.3797

Ttm = 1.3797

Now, the medium impedances

N1 = N0/n1 = 377/1.45 = 260 ohm
N2 = N0/n2 = 377/4.1  = 91.95 ohm

so we can write the E incident field as

E = 1y+(cos(40°)z+sin(40°)x)*e^(-j*pi/2)

**first question:** is this e^(-j*pi/2) (due circular left-hand polarization) right?

and we can write the incidente field in space-time

E(r,t) = cos(wt+kx*x-kz*z)+(0.766z+0.643x)*cos(wt+kx*x-kz*z-pi/2)

**second question:** is this equation right? with this -pi/2 phase

so we can get the E reflected wave

Er(r,t) = Rte*cos(wt+kx*x-kz*z)+Rtm*(0.766z+0.643x)*cos(wt+kx*x-kz*z-pi/2)
Er(r,t) = (-0.5647)*cos(wt+kx*x-kz*z)+(0.3797)*(-0.766z+0.643x)*cos(wt+kx*x-kz*z-pi/2)

**third question:** is this equation right?

amd transmitted field:

Et(r,t) = Tte*cos(wt+kx*x-kz*z)+Ttm*(N2/N1)*(0.766z+0.643x)*cos(wt+kx*x-kz*z-pi/2)
Et(r,t) = (0.4353)*cos(wt+kx*x-kz*z)+0.4879*(0.766z+0.643x)*cos(wt+kx*x-kz*z-pi/2)

**fourth question:** is this equation right?

so, the phase of reflectec and transmitted waves are -pi/2, but the amplitudes are different

reflectec: |(-0.5647)| != |(0.3797)| so, elliptical
transmitted: |(0.4353)| != |0.4879| so, elliptical

**fifth question:** but, for auxiliary angle of an ellipse ( tan(phi) = ay/ax )(Ulaby-Fundamentals of Applied Electromagnetics) who is 'ax' if i have a amplitude of x+z  and not for only x?

if i consider ax = |ax+az|

so i can calculate the auxiliary angle

phi = arctan( 0.5647/0.3797 ) = 56.08°

rotation angle 'w'

tan(2w) = tan(2phi)cos(d)

where's d is the angle from the cossines, so -pi/2

w = 0

and the ellipticity angle X

sin(2X)=sin(2phi)sin(d)
X = 1/2 arcsin(-sin(2phi)) = -33,92°

**sixth question:** is rotation angle is 0, why ellipticity angle isn't equal to auxiliary angle?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the physics stack exchange! Since this is not a typical help site, it would be great to ask questions to benefit the wider audience. You could improve your post by **elaborating your question, explaining where you encounter the problem and what your progress is so far, and making the question a bit more focused**.

Comment: You can refer to this link for more details : [How to ask homework type questions on this site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).
 In case you find these rules to be a bit harsh, you can always [go to any other suitable sites](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

As someone said before, you can learn the alphabet from these sites and then come back here to ask questions about dinosaurs :)
Have a great time!